# Raspberry Pi not connecting to cable modem

Tags: raspbian, networking

When I connect my Raspberry Pi to my cable modem, via Ethernet cable, it won't connect to the internet. The LAN light on the modem turns red when I connect to my Raspberry Pi. When I run `ifconfig`, I get a ip address for `eth0`.

The Ethernet cable is new, as is the modem (they came in the same package). The modem is not a modem/router combo.

I'm trying to setup my Raspberry Pi as router.

Comment: Can you give us the IP adress you get for eth0, and the modem model ?

Comment: Inet address: 169.254.227.13.

Comment: Model of cable modem is Zoom 5345.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computers use `169.254.x.x` addresses when they have a physical link to a router / modem, but they can't receive an IP address. (See [here](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/A/APIPA.html) for more information about Automatic Private IP Addressing).

Things to try:

- Restart your modem
- Force a new IP - `dhclient -r eth0`
- Restart your Raspberry Pi
- Check the Ethernet cable works on other machines
- Try using a different Ethernet cable

Comment: Restarting the modem while the Ethernet was plugged into the Raspberry Pi worked!